# Adding new Result type in Search site of SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, search-results, refinement-panel

I have added new file type (e.g. xyz) in Crawling section of Search administration of SharePoint 2013. I also added new Result type in SharePoint search site with condition: FileType Equal any off.. xyz

I can search documents that have xyz extension but this 'Result Type' refinement is not coming on SharePoint search site.

I want to refine my search results for custom file type by adding new Result type refinement label. Any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Refiners are mapped to managed properties, as in SP 2010. in [this post](http://aghy.hu/AghyBlog_EN/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=181)
you can get examples of how you can modify and add new refiners for Sharepoint 2013 search.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution similar to the question asked by this thread [Video file type in refinement panel](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101078/video-file-type-in-refinement-panel/104216) see the accepted answer by the user.