# Video file type in refinement panel

Tags: 2013, search-results, refinement-panel

I need to show file type in refinement panel with types such as wmv, avi, mp4, mpeg so that users can refine based on these types.

I tried adding the above file types in CentralAdmin -> Search Service -> File Types

After that I did a full crawl.

But still it is not showing in the file type refiner.

What am I missing?

Comment: Take a look at this blog series http://www.eliostruyf.com/part-3-working-with-file-types-in-the-search-refiner-control-template/, part 1, 2 and 3 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the custom file type extensions which we add to the central admin will be available in the file types when we preview the refinement panel.

But the filetypes what we see is different, we see user friendly names for that.

Say for xlsx we see Excel and for ppt we see PowerPoint and so on.

So i checked the display template for the refinement panel.

In the filter_default.html, i Found a function for mapping the extensions.

```
    function mapResultType(listData)
        {
            var map = { };
            map[Srch.U.loadResource("rf_ResultTypeRefinerValue_MSAccess")] = {
                "RefinerName": "FileType",
                "RefinementValues": ["accdb", "accdc", "accde", "accdr", "accdt"]
            };
            map[Srch.U.loadResource("rf_ResultTypeRefinerValue_AdobePDF")] = {
                "RefinerName": "FileType",
                "RefinementValues": ["pdf"]
            }; 
    .....
    .....
            map[Srch.U.loadResource("rf_ResultTypeRefinerValue_MSExcel")] = {
                "RefinerName": "FileType",
                "RefinementValues":        ["odc", "ods", "xls", "xlsb", "xlsm", "xlsx", "xltm", "xltx", "xlam"]
            }; 
            map[Srch.U.loadResource("rf_ResultTypeRefinerValue_Image")] = {
                "RefinerName": "FileType",
                "RefinementValues": ["bmp", "jpeg", "png", "tiff", "gif", "rle", "wmf", "dib", "ico", "wpd", "odg"]
            };
    .....
    .....
}
```

Towards the last i added a mapping for Video also as below:

```
map["Video File"] = {
    "RefinerName": "FileType",
    "RefinementValues": ["wmv","avi","mp4","mpeg"]
};
```

And now i am able to see the video file type in refinement panel when i have videos in the serach result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a managed property for this. Simply allowing the file types in CA will not add them to refiner panel.
If the files are coming from a library, create a calculated column and populate the extension there for each item.
Run a full crawl and crawled property with ows_"ColumnName" will be created.

Then create a managed property and map it with the above crawled property. Check the refiner property check box. Run a Full Crawl.

Edit the refiner panel and then you will be able to choose the refiner there.

Comment: So you say it is not possible to add file types to the built in file type refiner?

Comment: @Suraj wants to add it in Refinement Panel. So the file extensions should be indexed hence we need to have a dedicated managed property which holds its values so that it could be refined.

Comment: It is already indexed, and there is already a refiner for it: http://www.eliostruyf.com/part-3-working-with-file-types-in-the-search-refiner-control-template/

Comment: @RobertLindgren thanks, didn't knew about it.

Comment: @varun-verma there are default properties like file type and file extension managed property in CA, so why we need to add a new column and have a corresponding managed property. already we are using File Type refiner, adding one more refiner is awkward.

Comment: @Robert-lindgren can you help me to show the newly added filetypes in CA in search result

Comment: I refer you to the link

Comment: Suraj you are right, was not aware of it. Please check link given by Robert

Comment: @Robert-lindgren as per the link, it creates a custom refiner, can you say why i need to create a custom refiner. Since the file type won't be shown in video result source, creating a custom refiner will enable this file type. Please comment

Comment: Well basically because you will have to update and write some custom logic...

Answer (score -1):

Just add

```
map[Srch.U.loadResource("rf_ResultTypeRefinerValue_Video")] = {
    "RefinerName": "FileType",
    "RefinementValues": ["wmv","avi","mp4","mpeg"]
};
```

and it works for SP Online

Comment: I used Google Translate to translate the answer.  If I got it wrong, please fix or revert.